# why is one of a parcel's attributes nan?

Tags: android, android-intent, parcel

I have an object that I want to send to an activity like an extra to intent, I used parcel, I succeeded in sending all the attributes except of one -'longitude' that arrives as NAN, I don't know why

this is my class:

```
private String city;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

public Place(String city, double longitude, double latitude) {
    this.city = city;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Place() {
}

protected Place(Parcel in) {
    city = in.readString();
    longitude = in.readDouble();
latitude=in.readDouble();
}

public static final Creator<Place> CREATOR = new Creator<Place>() {
    @Override
    public Place createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Place(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Place[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Place[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(city);
    parcel.writeDouble(latitude);
    parcel.writeDouble(longitude);
}
```

this is my call to writeToParcel:

```
intent.putExtra("myPlace", myPlace);
```

this is call to getParcelableExtra:

```
myPlace=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("myPlace");
```

Comment: Have you checked the place attributes value before/after parcelling the place instance ? Maybe the attribute was NaN before parcelling ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to read back the latitude value when unparceling the Place object ; the constructor should be like

```
protected Place(Parcel in) {
    city = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readDouble();
    longitude = in.readDouble();
}
```

Modern IDEs (like Android Studio) has options to generate the parcel methods implementation, which tends to avoid forgetting fields when parcelling / unparcelling objects.

Comment: soory, I just copy the code because I want it to be more clear so I forgot copy this line, But in my real code I have this line- so this is not the answer